# Domain of the Total Derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential

Suppose I have some map $F: \mathbb{R^{m}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^{n}}$. I'm struggling to get an intuitive understanding of the meaning of the total derivative $dF_p: \mathbb{R^{m}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^{n}}$ at a point $p \in \mathbb{R^{m}}$. This will obviously be represented some $n \times m$ matrix. Now, each entry in this matrix will be of the form $\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j}$, and thus will be a function of $(x_1,...,x_m)$.

As I understand, we input the values of $p \in \mathbb{R^{m}}$ into this matrix, thus giving an $n \times m$ matrix of real numbers, and then this defines the map $dF_p: \mathbb{R^{m}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^{n}}$.

However, the Regular Value Theorem states that we require this map to be surjective. This implies that we will be able to apply $dF_p$ to any point $q \in \mathbb{R^{m}}$ (otherwise how are we able to $hit$ all of the values in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$?) But this map is the differential at $p$, and so how does this make sense to apply it anywhere other than $p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't apply the matrix to $p$. Informally, you apply it to a vector pointing *away from* $p$. The idea is this: for each point $p\in\mathbb R^n$ at which $F$ is differentiable,you may find a linear map $\mathrm dF_p:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ such that
$$F(p+v)\approx F(p)+\mathrm dF_p(v).$$
Here, $\approx$ means that a certain limit is $0$ as $v$ goes to $0$, but that's not important for my answer. So if you want to approximate $F(p+v)$, you only need to apply the linear map to $v$. You don't apply it to points in the domain, but to vectors pointing between points. This may not be obvious in the setting of vector spaces as domains, but it's a bit more natural in the setting of affine spaces: an affine space is a set of points $A$ together with a vector space $V$ which describes vectors pointing between the points. If we have a differentiable map between the point sets of affine spaces, the differential is a linear map between the vector spaces associated with the affine spaces. So the differential of a function at a point has a genuinely different domain and range than the function itself. It's just that in the setting of vector spaces, the set of points and the set of vectors pointing between the points is the same, so the difference is less apparent.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So to clarify, the $v$ that you refer to above is in fact a totally different object to $p$ (a tangent vector instead of a point), and $dF_{p}$ map's domain is tangent vectors. This makes sense. However I am not understanding the relevance of the point $p$. I suppose this boils down to the question what is the difference between the maps $dF_{p}$ and $dF_{q}$ for $p \neq q$?

Comment: Differentiability is a property that functions have at certain points, not globally (at first, at least). The differential $\mathrm dF_p$ is the linear map which allows us to approximate $F$ if we are close to $p$. The differential $\mathrm dF_q$ allows us to approximate $F$ if we are close to $q$. We may need different maps to do this, since $F$ may look totally different around $p$ than it does around $q$. So the index $p$ determines how the linear map acts. And then once we know how it acts, we can apply it to tangent vectors.

Comment: You say F may look totally different around $p$ than it does around $q$,and we may need different maps to approximate $F$ near both these points. If we have the following as a simple example $F:\mathbb{R^{3}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $F(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1^{2} + x_2^{2} - x_3^{2}$ then for distinct points $p, q\in \mathbb{{R^3}}$ I believe we would have $dF_p = dF_q = (2x_1, 2x_2, -2x_3)$. These are independent of $p, q$ (which was my original motivation for subbing in $p$, $q$ so that we could distinguish between the two). If this is correct, when would we ever have $dF_p$ and $dF_q$ distinct?

Comment: $p$ and $q$ determine the coordinates $x_1,x_2,x_3$. $If $p=(1,2,3)$ and $q=(3,2,1)$, then $\mathrm dF_p=(2,4,-6)$ and $\mathrm dF_q=(6,4,-2)$, which are different!